# Search an Array containing strings of names, return names with length of X

Tags: ruby

Given an array `["Jim Bob", "Jim","Billy Bob"]`,

How do I return an array with all names whose length is X.

So, if I searched the array for names with a length of 2, I should return:`["Jim Bob", "Billy Bob"]`

Looking to do this in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you do not search names with a length of 2, but being composed of 2 names.

Select by the number of name parts:

```
["Jim Bob", "Jim", "Billy Bob"].select { |names| names.split.length == 2 }
#=> ["Jim Bob", "Billy Bob"]
```

Select by the number of spaces in the name:

```
["Jim Bob", "Jim", "Billy Bob"].select { |name| name.count(' ') == 1 }
#=> ["Jim Bob", "Billy Bob"]
```

Comment: That is very weird...I upvoted your answer. I have no clue why it would have been downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to treat hyphenated names, you may want:

```
arr = ["Jim Bob", "Jim", "Billy Bob", "Anna-Marie"]

arr.select { |names| names.scan(/[\w-]+/).size == 2 }
  #=> ["Jim Bob", "Billy Bob"]
```